# ことで in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 本当に仲のおよろしいことで

What is this ことで ?

About the context, the person said to two people that their relationship looked good. That is the sentence I provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 本当に仲のおよろしい**ことで**

This phrase is the short form of 本当{ほんとう}に仲{なか}のおよろしいことで**何{なに}よりです**.

The function of 「こと」 in this phrase is to make the preceding phrase 本当{ほんとう}に仲{なか}のおよろしい to be a noun clause and also **to express the speaker's admiration or exclamation which is written in Chocolate's Answer**, and the function of 「で」 is to make the noun clause to be the reason for the following phrase 何{なに}よりです.

Then the whole phrase means: You are 何{なに}よりです because you are 本当{ほんとう}に仲{なか}のおよろしい.

何{なに}よりです is the short form of 何{なに}より素晴{すば}らしい meaning "better than anything else."

本当{ほんとう}に仲{なか}のおよろしい is the polite expression of 本当{ほんとう}に仲{なか}がよい meaning "truely be on good terms with each other."

Answer (score 5):

> 本当に仲のおよろしいことで

I think the こと here is used in the sense of:

> こと【事】〘名詞〙
>   ❿ ㋑ 感動・詠嘆を表す。
>   「故郷の山は何と懐かしい**こと**だ」「いやあ、うらやましい**こと**で…」
>   （表現）「・・・ことです（丁寧語）」「・・・こった」などのバリエーションがある。
>   「まあ、景色の美しい**こと**」など、「だ」を伴わない言い方も多い。
>   （明鏡国語辞典）

The こと expresses the speaker's 感動・詠嘆 (admiration or exclamation).

And, the overly polite およろしい sounds rather sarcastic to me; I'd expect 本当に仲のいいことで or maybe 本当に仲のよろしいことで in a normal situation.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now, what about mackygoo's answer ? Are both of your answers correct ?